# How to implement a spinlock to avoid blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization, spinlock

Consider the following code:

```
// Below block executed by thread t1
synchronized(obj) {
   obj.wait(0);
}

// This block executed by thread t2
synchronized(obj) {
    obj.notify();
}
```

I understand that in above code if `t1` has taken ownership of synchronized block and at the same time if thread `t2` tries to take synchronized block, then `t2` goes for a kernel wait.
I want to avoid this situation and spin `t2` before the block until `t1` calls wait and leaves ownership of the block. Is that possible?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your post before hitting submit - use the preview to see what the post will look like, and only submit it when it looks how you'd want it to look if  *you* were answering the question.

Comment: Additionally, do you have evidence that this is actually causing a problem in your code? A spin lock is very rarely the right solution - and bear in mind that `t1` will relinquish the lock as soon as it calls `wait()`, so the window of opportunity for t2 blocking is really very small.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Instead on one thread waiting on the lock, you'd have one thread waiting on the lock, and at the same time wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: my use of this code block is too chatty, multiple threads wait and notify, i dont want my thread to go in kernal waits rather i can spin a little and acquire the ownership

Comment: Agree that the OP should expand on the "why" - but if there was never a good need, then the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package would not have been created.

Comment: @ThomasStets probably because of the cargo-cult 'blocking bad, non-blocking good'.

Comment: @Erwin that package was created for totally different purposes than to control if and how long a lock spins before making the kernel call (where does it even allow that? Never ran into it). For really good reasons - that's an implementation detail that the JVM can handle perfectly fine on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM need not implement entry to a locked synchronized block as a hard block and context switch. [It has the option of using lighter weight methods, such as spin locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325824/does-any-jvm-implement-blocking-with-spin-waiting). In fact, the Oracle JVM goes to [some lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20689718/545127) to avoid blocking. So you might find that the JVM has already done this optimisation for you. And if it has not, that might be because the JVM has evidence that a spin lock would be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Raedwald, Can you share any links that suggest this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class SpinLock {

   private AtomicBoolean locked = new AtomicBoolean(false);

   public void lock() {
      while (!locked.compareAndSet(false, true));
   }

   public void unlock() {
      locked.set(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: No need for CAS to implement a SpinLock.
Changing the loop by something like while (getAndSet(true) == true) will probably rely on a more lightly xchg instruction. But there is more to it and probably best to rely on the JVM to do what's right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do what you want.

An implementation of the interface `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` (such as `ReentrantLock`) allows you to busy-wait for a lock using the `tryLock` method (invoked from a loop).

To implement `wait` and `notify` functionality, you call the method `newCondition` on `Lock` to obtain a `Condition` object. The `Condition` interface has the methods `await` and `signal`/`signalAll` that work analogous to `wait` and `notify`/`notifyAll`.

Answer (score -3):

Its very easy to implement [spinlock in Java](http://tech693.blogspot.com/2018/08/java-spin-lock-implementation.html). The idea here is to take advantage of tryLock() method of Lock interface.

```
 import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class SpinLock extends ReentrantLock{

public SpinLock() {
  super();
 }


 public void lock() {
  while(!super.tryLock()) {
    // Do Nothing
  }

 }

 public void unlock() {
  super.unlock();
 }

}
```

Reference: https://tech693.blogspot.com/2018/08/java-spin-lock-implementation.html