# How to create a session scoped thread safe object instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, architecture, synchronization

I want to have a **resettable** object instance for a **session** within my program that is thread safe, an example of a session might be a logged in user session.

I am currently doing something like this;

```
  public final class ObjectFactory {

    private static volatile NativeObjectWrapper instance = null;

    private Singleton() {}

    public static NativeObjectWrapper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(ObjectFactory.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new NativeObjectWrapper(AuthData);
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void reset() {
      synchronized(ObjectFactory.class) {
        instance = null;
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to have the object created lazily, **with the ability to reset it**. Is the above approach threadsafe? if not is there a common pattern to solve this?

An example again would be that scoped object here has some inner data based on the user session and therefore should be a new instance per user session.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542017/java-singleton-with-an-inner-class-what-guarantees-thread-safety

Comment: Thats not the same though is it, they are examples of a singleton, not one with the ability to reset it state.

Comment: I see. Didn't notice you had a `reset` method. You might want to emphasize it in the question if that's something you need. Generally, singletons are forever.

Comment: Do you want a singleton or a session scoped object? This reset business makes me think you have something askew with your design. What does the singleton contain?

Comment: Im hoping for a session scoped object, this object hooks into c code and requires passing authentication data. I need to keep an instance of this object for the lifetime a user is logged in, as its my hook into native C code. Maybe what im really after is some kind of thread safe holder to keep this instance as a scoped object.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the above approach threadsafe?

No, it is not.

Say we have two threads - `A` and `B`.

`A` calls `getInstance()`, passes the `instance==null` check, and then there's a context switch to `B`, which calls `reset()`. After `B` finishes executing `reset()`, `A` gets the context again and returns `instance`, which is now null.

> if not is there a common pattern to solve this?

I don't remember seening singletons with a `reset` method, so I'm not aware of any *common* patterns for this problem. However, the simplest solution would be to just remove the first `if (instance == null)` check in `getInstance()`. This would make your implementation thread safe, as `instance` is always checked and modified within a synchronized block. In this scenario, you could also remove the `volatile` modifier from `instance` since it is always accessed from within a synchronized block.

There are more complex solutions I can think of, but I'd use them only if real-world profiling showed that you're spending too much time blocked on that `synchronized` block. Note that the JVM has [some sophisticated ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26711357/3199595) of avoiding using "real" locks to minimize blocking.

One trickier approach could be to read the `instance` field just once:

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    Singleton toReturn = instance;
    if (toReturn == null) {
        synchronized(SingletonFactory.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Singleton();
                toReturn = instance;
            }
        }
    }

    return toReturn ;
}
```

But this could result in returning an old "instance". For example a thread could execute `Singleton toReturn = instance` and get a valid instance, then lose the CPU. At this point, a 1000 other threads could create and reset 1000 other instances until the original thread gets a spin on the CPU again, at which point it returns an old `instance` value. It's up to you whether such a case is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the above approach threadsafe?

The answer depends on what you think "thread safe" means.  There is nothing in your `reset()` method to prevent a thread that previously called `getInstance()` from continuing to use the old instance.

Is that "thread safe?"

Generally speaking, "thread safe" means that the actions of one thread can never cause other threads to see shared data in an inconsistent or invalid state. But what "inconsistent" or "invalid" mean depends on the structure of the shared data (i.e., on the design of the application.)

---

Another way of looking at it: If somebody tells you that a *class* is "thread safe," then they're probably telling you that concurrent calls to the class's methods by multiple threads will not do anything that disagrees with the class documentation and, will not do anything that disagrees with how a reaonable programmer thinks the class *should* behave in cases where the documentation is not absolutely clear.

NOTE: That is a weaker definition of "thread safety" because it glosses over the fact that, using thread-safe components to build a system does not guarantee that the system itself will be thread-safe.

Does everybody who uses your class *clearly* understand that no thread in the program may ever call `reset()` while any reference to the old singleton still exists? If so, then I would call that a weak design because it is very far from being "junior-programmer-safe," but I would grudgingly admit that, from a strict, language-lawyerly point of view, you could call your `ObjectFactory` class  "*thread* safe."